How long for boiling water to cool down in a cooler?
I have no knowledge in physics but I drink green tea, and it requires water at 70 degree (so does the package say). My boiler can only heat to 100 degrees (not below), so I would like to know how long it takes for 1 liter of water to cool down from 100 degrees to 70 degrees celsius if the cap is closed (obviously not completely)
The boiler can contain at maximum 1.7 liters and is made of plastic.

With such little information the best advice is to get a thermometer and do the experiment.

Mix boiling water with the coldest water you can get from your tap or fridge in approx. 70:30 ratio. Close enough.

"I have no knowledge in physics but I drink green tea". What a great introduction :-)
